# Nextjs: Type 'OmitWithTag<GetServerSidePropsContext<ParsedUrlQuery>, keyof PageProps, "default">' does not satisfy '{ [x: string]: never; }'

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have a working app in dev mode that crashes when running the build command.

The output of `npm run build` is the following:

```
> next-app-template@0.0.1 build
> next build                   

 ✓ Creating an optimized production build    
 ✓ Compiled successfully 
   Linting and checking validity of types  ...Failed to compile.

.next/types/app/home/page.ts:26:13
Type error: Type 'OmitWithTag<GetServerSidePropsContext<ParsedUrlQuery>, keyof PageProps, "default">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'.
  Property 'req' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type 'IncomingMessage & { cookies: Partial<{ [key: string]: string; }>; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.

  24 | 
  25 | // Check the prop type of the entry function
> 26 | checkFields<Diff<PageProps, FirstArg<TEntry['default']>, 'default'>>()
```

I am using the 13.5.6 version of Next.js and the 18.12.0 version of Node.

It seems that the code compiles, but this error is raised. The message mentions that the property `req` is incompatible, but it is not used anywhere in the code.

EDIT: It seems that the problems is because of `@auth0/nextjs-auth0`. My main page is structured as follows:

```js
import { withPageAuthRequired } from "@auth0/nextjs-auth0";
import React from "react";

export default withPageAuthRequired(function HomePage() {
  return (
    <main>
      ...
    </main>
  );
});
```

However, the error disappears if I remove the `withPageAuthRequired` wrapper. I am using the 3.5.0 version of @auth0/nextjs-auth0.

Any help or advice for dealing with this?

Answer (score 0):

The only fix I found is temporarily ignoring error builds, as seen in https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/8380. Thus, temporarily modify the next.config.js file:

```json
typescript: {
    ignoreBuildErrors: true,
  },
```